# How to declare Android application category?

Tags: java, android

I have an Android application that I'd like to appear categorized as a Music Player. How do I do this?

[Here's](https://github.com/smithdtyler/prettygoodmusicplayer/issues/92) an issue request opened by a user for this question.

I know that I can add intent filters to Activities in the application, but it's unclear to me what intent filter to use, and which Activitie(s) should have the filter declared.

Comment: "I'd like to appear categorized as a Music Player" -- categorized in what?

Comment: Maybe this is a misunderstanding on my part - in the referenced Github bug report the user says that the application isn't detected as a music player. Presumably this is a function of the Android OS, though I guess it could just be particular flavors of Android?

Answer (score 2):

In your *AndroidManifest.xml* declares a filter in the activity that a will receive the file in this way:

```
<activity android:name=".PrincipalActivity"
          android:label="@string/app_name">
  <intent -filter>
     <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
     <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
     <category android:name="android.intent.category.CATEGORY_APP_MUSIC " />
  </intent>
</activity>
```

The category `android.intent.category.CATEGORY_APP_MUSIC` be accompanied by action `android.intent.action.MAIN`.

For more details take a look at [this](http://developer.android.com/intl/ja/reference/android/content/Intent.html#CATEGORY_APP_MUSIC).

Comment: I keep forgetting that these various categories exist. +1.

Comment: Any thoughts on how to test this? I added it to my application, but I don't know how to get my phone to display apps by category.

Comment: If what you're trying to do is show the menu of applications sorted by category and I think that you can't be an official version of Android. The only thing you can do is manage the resources of other applications, such as text, images, links, etc. When an application allows you to use one of these resources in another application, a dialog will open with all applications that allow the use of the resource according to the categories to which the target application is added.